# Powershell. Get free Azure Service Plan, without apps/slots

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-web-app-service

Perhaps anyone was trying to get unused resources in Azure by Powershell. I'm interested in a specific resource Azure Service Plan for app services.

I found out how to get resources without apps but stuck with slots. Because resource it-self has 2 type of services running **app/slots**. After all I get list of App Service without apps but some are with slots. Question is how to get 0/0 resources.

There is a *numberOfSites* parameter for this purpose but what about slots?

Anyone, please.

```
$RT = "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms"
$farms = Get-AzureRmResource -ODataQuery "`$filter=resourcetype eq 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms'"
foreach ($farm in $farms){
    $full_farm = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName $farm.ResourceGroupName -ResourceType $RT -ResourceName $farm.Name
    if ($full_farm.Properties.numberOfSites -eq '0'){
Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName $farm.ResourceGroupName -ResourceType $RT -ResourceName $farm.Name | Select-Object Name,ResourceGroupName,Location,Sku
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try my script below, it works on my side.

**Note**: The [azure function consumption plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#consumption-plan) is not included in my sample.

```
$RT = "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms"
$farms = Get-AzureRmResource -ODataQuery "`$filter=resourcetype eq 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms'"
foreach ($farm in $farms){
$usage = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName $farm.ResourceGroupName -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/usages -ResourceName $farm.Name -ApiVersion 2018-02-01
    if($farm.Kind -ne 'functionapp'){
       if($farm.Sku.Name -eq 'F1' -or $farm.Sku.Name -eq 'D1'){
           if (($usage | Where-Object {$_.unit -eq 'Sites'}).currentValue -eq '0'){
           Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName $farm.ResourceGroupName -ResourceType $RT -ResourceName $farm.Name | Select-Object Name,ResourceGroupName,Location,Sku
           }
}else{
      if(($usage | Where-Object {$_.unit -eq 'Sites'}).currentValue -eq '1'){
           Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName $farm.ResourceGroupName -ResourceType $RT -ResourceName $farm.Name | Select-Object Name,ResourceGroupName,Location,Sku
           }
       }
    }
}
```

[image]

**Check in the portal**:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where did you find this class "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/usages"? I'm trying to find in Microsoft docs, nothing. Could you please share the source. Thanks!

Comment: I'm also stuck with Cloud Services (Classic), didn't found anything about how to find "Stopped" status, or all stopped instances inside the resource. Would be very grateful if you will give a hint or something! Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: @OlehTarasenko Hi, for the /usage, you could check it in your service plan in the resource explorer. About the question of cloud service, you may need ask it in a new post, stackoverflow avoid to ask several questions in the same post.:-)